# How can I export Angular 2 Frontend Express JS variable to a Angular 2 component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, express

Based on my research I am doing the following with my code. Currently I am getting the following errors in my console and I do not see why. I followed a tutorial line by line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to export the variable of nameid from my routes.js file to be used in an Angular component.

**angular-master/express/config/routes.js**

```js
var xmldoc = require('xmldoc');
var DOMParser = require('dom-parser');
module.exports = function (app, config, passport) {

  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.redirect('/home')
  });

  app.get('/login',
    passport.authenticate(config.passport.strategy,
      {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/login'
      })
  );

  app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('body saml:', req.body.SAMLResponse);
    const body = req.body.SAMLResponse;
    var b = new Buffer(body, 'base64');
 let text = b.toString('ascii');
    //var inflated = pako.inflateRaw(b, {to:'string'}); 
    console.log('formmatted saml',text);
     var document = new xmldoc.XmlDocument(text);
  console.log('formmatted document',document);
     var status = document.descendantWithPath("samlp:Status").firstChild.attr;
    
   var attr = text.includes("AttributeStatement");
   var nameid = text.substring(text.lastIndexOf("<NameID>") + 8,text.lastIndexOf("</NameID>"));
   module.exports.nameid = nameid;
    console.log("status id:", status['Value']);
 console.log(attr);
   console.log('LDAP DB username: ' + nameid);
  
  

};
```

**angular-master/src/app/site/user-history/user-history.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { element } from 'protractor';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

var routes = require('./../../../../express/config/routes.js');


@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-history',
  templateUrl: './user-history.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../style.css']
})
export class UserHistoryComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {}


  ngOnInit() {
   console.log(routes.nameid); 


}
```

My console shows the following errors:

```html
xmldoc.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at xmldoc.js:5
    at Object../node_modules/xmldoc/lib/xmldoc.js (xmldoc.js:339)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at Object../node_modules/xmldoc/index.js (index.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at Object../express/config/routes.js (routes.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at Object../src/app/site/user-history/user-history.component.ts (user-history.component.ts:23)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at Object../src/app/site/site.module.ts (main.js:8001)
(anonymous) @ xmldoc.js:5
./node_modules/xmldoc/lib/xmldoc.js @ xmldoc.js:339
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
./node_modules/xmldoc/index.js @ index.js:3
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
./express/config/routes.js @ routes.js:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
./src/app/site/user-history/user-history.component.ts @ user-history.component.ts:23
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
./src/app/site/site.module.ts @ main.js:8001
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
./src/app/app.module.ts @ app.component.ts:13
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
./src/main.ts @ environmentLoader.ts:21
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
0 @ main.ts:16
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:43
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:30
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
```

Comment: changed tag to angularjs --> angular version is lower then 2

Comment: Hope you understand that usually Express lives on server and Angular lives in browser -- and fact that both are JavaScript does not change anything here.

Comment: To be honest I do not understand. I have what I believe are two instances of express. An express backend that I use to make calls to my database and an express that lives inside a folder in my Angular environment that is used for the SAML login. Does that make any sense?

I am just trying to pass a variable from my routes.js file in the Express folder of my Angular env to an Angular component. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Oops you must use import instead of require.

```
import * as routes from './../../../../express/config/routes.js';
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(routes.nameid); 
}
```

But why invoking a backend variable in front end ? they are separated servers

Comment: Thanks for reaching out -- I am currently still receiving the same error in my console.

My end game is to capture a part of the SAML metadata created in the login process to use in a database call by Angular.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that Node js is a server-side framework and Angular is a Frontend framework, both need to be compiled.

Since both are javascript you thought server code can be imported in the frontend. But Angular's package.json and angular.json file don't know the routes.js and it will not compile it.

Angular will be loaded inside browsers as plain HTML and javascript.

You need to create an API and try to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

`global` is nodejs global object, like `window` in browser. It's nodejs-only, doesn't exist in browser environment. That explains the error.

Thing is, express code lives in nodejs runtime on server. Angular code lives in browser. These are two isolated environments that cannot access each other's variable like you try to do. It's simply impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You may have attempted this approach already, but try importing the specific variable you're using, instead of everything.

For example:
`import { nameid } from './../../../../express/config/routes.js'`